# create a list of date and time in shell script

Tags: bash, shell

I try to run script to find the missing dates in a file "date_meta", therefore I try to write a list of whole dates using shell script and put it in file "date_correct". The format is %d%H%M with increment of 30 minutes. I get this error: line 9: [[: 2022-01-01T00: value too great for base (error token is "01T00")

The script:

```
#!/bin/sh 
strdate='2022-01-01T00:00'
enddate='2022-01-31T23:30'
while [[ ${strdate} -le ${enddate} ]] ; do 
echo $strdate>>date_correct 
strdate=$(date -d "$strdate 30 minute" +%d%H%M) 
done 
diff date_metar date_correct >output
```

Comment: What is `diff` command / function here?

Comment: Missing quotes I guess `while [[ "${strdate}" -le "${enddate}" ]] ; do`. Check syntax on shellcheck.net

Comment: `-le` is for comparing numbers. `2022-01-01T00:00` is interpreted as `2022 - 01 - 01T00  : 00`. `01T00` is not a valid number, hence the error.

Comment: for string comparison you need to look at using `<`, `>`, `!=`, `==` and/or negation of the comparison (eg, `[[ ! 'abc' < 'def' ]]`); you're changing the format of the string stored in `strdate` so even if you get the comparison working you're now comparing strings with different formats; I'm not aware of `date` being able to do math on a date/time string ... probably going to be easier to work with epoch seconds, converting to the desired format when printing to `date_correct`

Comment: since your code is using different date/time formats it would be helpful if you could provide a sample from the `date_metar` file so we can know for certain what date/time format you need to work with

Answer (score 3):

Your best bet for generating the range of valid dates/times will probably come from combining two ideas:

- use epoch seconds for comparisons and math
- use `awk` (or comparable program) to replace the time-consuming `bash/while` loop

One `epoch(secs) / awk` idea:

```
strdate='2022-01-01T00:00'
enddate='2022-01-31T23:30'

strdate_s=$(date -d "${strdate}" +%s)
enddate_s=$(date -d "${enddate}" +%s)

inc_m=30
((inc_s = inc_m * 60))

awk -v ss="${strdate_s}" -v es="${enddate_s}" -v inc="${inc_s}" '
BEGIN { while ( ss <= es ) {
              print strftime("%d%H%M", ss)
              ss+=inc
        }
      }
' > date_correct
```

**NOTE:** as Fravadona's mentioned in the comments, `strftime()` requires `GNU awk` (aka `gawk`)

To show the performance improvement of using `awk` instead of the `bash/while` loop we'll modify OP's current code to use the `epoch(secs)` approach:

```
strdate='2022-01-01T00:00'
enddate='2022-01-31T23:30'

strdate_s=$(date -d "${strdate}" +%s)
enddate_s=$(date -d "${enddate}" +%s)

inc_m=30
((inc_s = inc_m * 60))

while [[ "${strdate_s}" -le "${enddate_s}" ]] ; do
    date -d "@${strdate_s}" +%d%H%M >> date_correct2
    ((strdate_s+=inc_s))
done
```

A `diff` of the outputs show both sets of code generate the same output:

```
$ diff date_correct date_correct2
               <<<=== no output
```

Results of running both processes under `time`:

```
# awk

real    0m0.042s
user    0m0.015s
sys     0m0.015s

# bash/while

real    0m46.412s
user    0m6.727s
sys     0m27.314s
```

So `awk` is about 1100x times faster than a comparable `bash/while` loop.

If the sole purpose of this date/time-generating code is simply to find the missing dates/times in the `date_metar` file then OP may want to consider using a single `awk` script to eliminate the need for the `date_correct` file ***and*** still determine what dates/times are missing from `date_metar` ... but that's for another Q&A ...

---

Looking a bit more into the performance issues of the `bash/while` loop ...

Replacing the `date` call with a comparable `printf -v` call:

```
while [[ "${strdate_s}" -le "${enddate_s}" ]] ; do
    printf -v new_date '%(%d%H%M)T' "${strdate_s}"
    echo "${new_date}" >> date_correct2
    ((strdate_s+=inc_s))
done
```

We see overall time is reduced from 46+ secs to 10+ secs:

```
real    0m10.127s
user    0m0.141s
sys     0m0.312s
```

We should be able to get a further improvement by moving the `>> date_correct2` to after the `done`, thus replacing 1400+ file open/close operations (`date ... >> date_correct2`) with a single file open/close operation (`done > date_correct2`)

```
while [[ "${strdate_s}" -le "${enddate_s}" ]] ; do
    printf -v new_date '%(%d%H%M)T' "${strdate_s}"
    echo "${new_date}"
    ((strdate_s+=inc_s))
done  > date_correct2
```

This speeds up the process by ~50x times (10+ secs down to 0.2 secs):

```
real    0m0.198s
user    0m0.141s
sys     0m0.000s
```

Thus reducing the `bash/while` loop overhead (compared to `awk`) from 1100x to 5x.

Answer (score 0):

`strftime()` does ***not*** require `gnu-awk ::: gawk`

> ```
> mawk1 'BEGIN { fmt = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S %Z ( epochs %s | %Y-%j )"
>
> print ORS, systime(), ORS ORS, strftime(fmt, systime()), ORS }'
> ```

```
1662840559 

2022-09-10 16:09:19 EDT ( epochs 1662840559 | 2022-253 )
```

you'll get a very tiny, almost statistically insignificant, speed gain via `mawk-1` :

> ```
> {m,g}awk -v  __='2022 01 01 00 00 00' \
>          -v ___='2022 01 31 23 30 00' '
>
> BEGIN {  _*= (_+=(_+=(_^=_<_)+_)^_)+_
>         __ = mktime(__)
>        ___ = mktime(___)
>
>       ____ = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S %Z ( %s | %Y-%j )"
> do {
>      print __, strftime(____,__) } while ((__+=_)<=___) }'
> ```

```
out9: 78.5KiB 0:00:00 [64.4MiB/s] [64.4MiB/s] [<=> ]
( mawk -v __='2022 01 01 00 00 00' -v ___='2022 01 31 23 30 00' -- ; )
0.01s user 0.00s system 89% cpu 0.019 total

  1484  1643682600 2022-01-31 21:30:00 EST ( 1643682600 | 2022-031 )
  1485  1643684400 2022-01-31 22:00:00 EST ( 1643684400 | 2022-031 )
  1486  1643686200 2022-01-31 22:30:00 EST ( 1643686200 | 2022-031 )
  1487  1643688000 2022-01-31 23:00:00 EST ( 1643688000 | 2022-031 )
  1488  1643689800 2022-01-31 23:30:00 EST ( 1643689800 | 2022-031 )
```

|

```
 out9: 78.5KiB 0:00:00 [17.0MiB/s] [17.0MiB/s] [<=> ]
 ( gawk -v __='2022 01 01 00 00 00' -v ___='2022 01 31 23 30 00' -be ; )
 0.02s user 0.01s system 85% cpu 0.026 total

  1484  1643682600 2022-01-31 21:30:00 EST ( 1643682600 | 2022-031 )
  1485  1643684400 2022-01-31 22:00:00 EST ( 1643684400 | 2022-031 )
  1486  1643686200 2022-01-31 22:30:00 EST ( 1643686200 | 2022-031 )
  1487  1643688000 2022-01-31 23:00:00 EST ( 1643688000 | 2022-031 )
  1488  1643689800 2022-01-31 23:30:00 EST ( 1643689800 | 2022-031 )
```